# Python - accessing an element from a JSON objects list

Tags: python, json

I'm new in using python. I've started with some json data, pandas and numpy.

I have a list of json objects stored into a txt file. I'm reading the data from the txt file and create a dictionary and then append to my json list each json object from the file.

```
jsonTweetsList = []
with open('tweetsOutput.txt') as f:
    for jsonObj in f:
        tweetDict = json.loads(jsonObj)
        jsonTweetsList.append(tweetDict)
```

An example of what the file contains:

***{"created_at":"Sat May 09 12:25:06 +0000 2020","text":"#wbdemotest disliked the taxes and fees","user": {"id":97750949378440806,"id_str":"977509493784408064","name":"Roxana Cepoiu","screen_name":"roxana_cepoiu"}}***

***{"created_at":"Sat May 09 12:25:44 +0000 2020","id":1259097218260312065,"id_str":"1259097218260312065","text":"#wbdemotest happy with new services provided","user":{"id":977509493784408064,"id_str":"977509493784408064","name":"Roxana Cepoiu","screen_name":"roxana_cepoiu"}}***

I try to access the name element from the user, but I do not know how. 
Using the below script it does not work for the user-name element, it is working only for created_at and text.

```
for tweet in jsonTweetsList:
    print(tweet["created_at"], tweet["text"],tweet["user"][0]["name"])
```

Can you advise me on how can I access the data from user-name?

Comment: Try `tweet['user']['name']`.

Answer (score 1):

`user` is not a list, it's just an object, what you need to do is access it directly without the `[0]` index

```
print(tweet["user"]["name"])
```

Comment: Worked in this way. Haha, thank you! Hard times being a beginner :D